# Laravel - How to share the session between two or more web apps?

Tags: php, authentication, session, single-sign-on, laravel-7

I have two Laravel projects, lets say A and B, with different database. The  login form of A has a select where user can choose project A or B to access.

Some points to considered:

- These projects will not be in the same domain.
- Project A database will use postgres.
- Project B database wil use mysql (Xampp).
- Driver session of A will use file.
- Driver session of B will use database.

what i tried so far is store session from B in its database, but i don't know how to save session if i try to login from A to B

Answer (score 0):

> Don't communicate by sharing memory, share memory by communicating.
>
> Go lang docs

It is not appropriate to share sessions between applications. The Laravel encrypts sessions by key so you need to share the keys between apps.

I suggest you use OAuth2 and app B can be a first-party of app A so you can do your authentication of app B with app A. Laravel implemented OAuth2 in the passport package.

It will like the relation between github.com and gist.github.com.

but if you need more flexibility I suggest you share auth sessions by communication between your apps. like two independent services.

Comment: First to all thanks for the reply, i considered use OAuth2, but i need to make some validations and process with the id of the user, and as far as i know OAuth doesn't share the user id from database, or am i wrong?
Any case i gonna take some deep read doc of OAuth2.

Comment: You can share the database user id or any data you want based on your implementation. for example, Facebook has multiple scopes and gets different data per toke privilege.